# Removing an element from a doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, logic, structure, doubly-linked-list

My code works for elements which are at the start of the linked list but not for the ones in the middle or the end. Appreciate your help!

```
void remove(){
    if (!head)
        printf("\nNo nodes to delete. List is empty.");
    else{
        int n;
        struct node* help = head;
        printf("Enter an element to delete: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(head->data == n){
            help-> next->prev = 0;
            head = help -> next;
        } else{
            while(help -> next){
                if(help -> data == n){
                    help -> next -> prev = help -> prev;
                    help -> prev -> next = help -> next;
                }
                else help = help -> next;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not have `n` as a parameter of `remove()`?

Comment: @meaning-matters why do people always nit-pick code instead of answering the question posed?  Your question has nothing to do with the problem being asked and the posted code may well be simplifed to post to SO - not the way it was actually written for the actual project by the asker.

Comment: @shail giving us specific examples of how it fails would be helpful, as your code has a lot of problems and it's difficult to point them all out without just rewriting your code for you (which should not be done on SO)

Comment: @xaxxon Well as a whole my program is for inserting and deleting nodes in a sorted doubly linked list. Insertion works and deleting the first node from the linked list works fine, except deleting the last node. Also, deleting nodes in the middle and end don't work. If I try to delete the last node, I am led back to main(); If I try deleting a node in the middle, the program crashes :|

Answer (score 1):

First, use NULL not 0 for meaning NULL.  In C, you need to.  In C++ it's optional, but you tagged the question C.

```
help-> next->prev = 0;
```

You never check to see if there is a second element.  If the list only has one element, this fails -- so it doesn't even always work for the first element.

```
        while(help -> next){
            if(help -> data == n){
```

This will stop you from ever deleting the last element, since you stop looking at the list once you get to (but before you deal with) the last element.  But even if you didn't, the next lines:

```
                help -> next -> prev = help -> prev;
                help -> prev -> next = help -> next;
```

will cause you to crash if it's the last one, since it's not checking that there is another element after.

Also, the spaces before and after the arrow `->` is pretty uncommon.  I'd suggest not doing that anymore.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these issues out. I'll try to rectify my code.

Comment: Should I add an if condition(only execute if next is not null) for executing help->next->prev = NULL;? Also, should I change my while condition to while(help)? I can't figure out how to change the code inside the while loop though.

Comment: @Shail yes.  there will be lots of conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node *head, *tail; //global head & tail

int delete_item() {
    int del_data = 0;
    struct node *item = head, *tmp;
    scanf("%d", &del_data);
    while(item){
        if(item->data == del_data){
            tmp = item;
            if(item->next){
                //it's not tail
                item->next->prev = item->prev;
            } 
            else {
                //it's tail
                tail = item->prev;
                if(tail)
                    tail->next = NULL;
            }
            if(item->prev){
                //it's not head
                item->prev->next = item->next;
            }
            else {
                //it's head
                head = item->next;
                if(head)
                    head->prev = NULL;
            }
            //free memory
            free(tmp);
        }
        //move forward
        item = item->next;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If he will try to understand this code then everything will be OK. Don't be so mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally working on that until I found this way to delete the node
in given position :

```
void delete (int n) {
  struct node *temp = head;
  if (n == 1) {
    head = temp->next;
    (temp->next)->prev = head;
    free(temp);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  if (temp->next != NULL) {
    (temp->next)->prev = temp->prev;
    (temp->prev)->next = temp->next;
  } else {
    (temp->prev)->next = NULL;
  }
  free(temp);
}
```